# How do I start BIOS programming?

Tags: bios

I have done so much research on how to program a BIOS from scratch but I got nothing.  Does anyone one have any kind of BIOS tutorial or guide, that would be much appreciated. I have gotten absolutely nowhere. It's probably not possible but I'm wanting at least a semi-universal BIOS, ideally using a virtual machine.

Comment: You mean, ideally, a strictly IBM-compatible BIOS for strictly IBM-compatible hardware?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing my own BIOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890048/writing-my-own-bios)

Comment: this question and mainly answers seemed helpful to me

Answer (score 9):

coreboot is an open source BIOS project that supports over 200 mainboards.  This could be a good place to start if you want to browse some code and get an idea of everything a bios has to accomplish.

http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot

Comment: +1 I like proposing opensource alternatives better than saying "no it's impossible".

Answer (score 6):

No. The only people with the information you're looking for are motherboard manufacturers, and they do not generally publish it.

Some projects to create an open BIOS exist (e.g, [Coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/)), but they depend significantly on reverse engineering. (They are also **extremely** limited in what they support.)

Comment: I'm sure there are people out there who reverse engineered at least some of it?

Comment: Somewhat, yes, for certain motherboards, but it's all inherently very hardware-specific. There is no universal documentation, and there may not be any information at all for the hardware the OP is using.